# getting data from 2 tables with one-to-many relation using limit and offset on a 'master' table

Tags: mysql, limit, one-to-many

This seems simple so I'm a little embarrassed to ask, but here it is: I've got 2 tables - orders and items (of orders). One order can have one or more items and I'd like to use LIMIT to get e.g. first 10 orders, possibly using OFFSET too so, the question is: how to create a query that would do that? For example, if order 1 has 2 items, order 2: 1 item, order 3: 2 items, order 4: 1 item, and I need first 3 orders the expected result would be:

1. order 1 item 1
2. order 1 item 2,
3. order 2 item 1,
4. order 3 item 1,
5. order 3 item 2

Comment: Get the 10 orders in a cte or a sub query then join the items table..or am I missing something

Comment: P.Salmon I can't use CTE (MySQL 5.7) but I would definitely experiment with that once I move to a better web host. Could you elaborate a little about the sub-query? I'm still learning MySQL - make it an answer and I'll accept it if you don't mind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a sub query to limit and given

```
MariaDB [sandbox]> select * from cat_books;
+--------+-------+
| idbook | name  |
+--------+-------+
|      1 | book1 |
|      2 | book2 |
|      3 | book3 |
|      4 | book4 |
+--------+-------+
4 rows in set (0.001 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> select * from books_sold;
+---------+--------+--------+
| id_sold | idbook | iduser |
+---------+--------+--------+
|       1 |      1 |      1 |
|       2 |      2 |      1 |
|       3 |      1 |      2 |
|       4 |      1 |      3 |
|       4 |      3 |      5 |
+---------+--------+--------+
5 rows in set (0.001 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]>
MariaDB [sandbox]> select *
    -> from
    -> (SELECT * FROM CAT_books order by idbook limit 2) cb
    -> join
    -> books_sold bs on bs.idbook = cb.idbook
    -> order by cb.idbook;
+--------+-------+---------+--------+--------+
| idbook | name  | id_sold | idbook | iduser |
+--------+-------+---------+--------+--------+
|      1 | book1 |       3 |      1 |      2 |
|      1 | book1 |       4 |      1 |      3 |
|      1 | book1 |       1 |      1 |      1 |
|      2 | book2 |       2 |      2 |      1 |
+--------+-------+---------+--------+--------+
4 rows in set (0.001 sec)
```

Comment: Ah, that way! I've been experimenting with something like this but what I missed putting a LIMIT in a sub query! Dear me, I need a rest! Thanx a lot!